# Simple reflections

Tags: algebraic-groups

From P210 of  "Linear algebraic groups and finite groups of Lie type" by Malle and Testerman.

Theorem 24.10 Let $G$ be connected reductive with Steinberg endomorphism $F : G → G$, $T ≤ B$ an $F$ -stable maximal torus in an $F$ -stable Borel
subgroup of $G$, $N := N_G(T)$. Then $B^F$ , $N^F$ is a BN-pair in $G^F$ with Weyl
group $W^F$ .

Corollary 24.11 In the situation of Theorem 24.10, let $U = R_u(B)$. Then
$U^F$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G^F$, with normalizer $N_{G^F} (U^F) = B^F$.

In the proof for this corollary, it states $N_{G^F}(U^F)$ is a parabolic subgroup of $G^F$. By(BN5), it does not contain any simple reflection, so it equals $B^F$.

By the way, BN5 is:
If $\dot{s}$ is in N, then $\dot{s}$B$\dot{s}$ $\neq$ B.

Why it has no simple reflection? Thank you!

Comment: Is your question, "Why does (BN5) imply $N_{G^F}(U^F)$ not contain any simple reflections?"? I'm not sure at which point you're confused, and also not sure what group you're saying does not contain a simple reflection

Comment: sorry for the delay. Yes. you're correct! thx!